# Dynamically fill a ListPreference

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to fill a ListPreference with the contents of the res/anim folder but I am having a problem it keeps coming up blank, I have a static array of strings to fill it and that works but I need it to be dynamic, I can print the text out in the logcat, its just not populating the list can you help me?

PreferenceActivityMenu.java

```
      CharSequence[] entries = null;
      CharSequence[] entryValues = null;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    ListPreference prefListAnim = new ListPreference(this);

    listAnim();

    prefListAnim.setEntries(entries);

    prefListAnim.setEntryValues(entryValues);


    }

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void listAnim() {
    Field[] fields = R.anim.class.getFields();
    entries = new String[fields.length];
    entryValues = new String[fields.length];

    for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) {
        Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
        entries[count] = fields[count].getName();

        entryValues[count] = Integer.toString(count);


    }
}
```

and preference.xml

```
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Animation Transitions" >


    <ListPreference 

        android:dialogTitle="@string/prefsList_dialogTitle"
        android:key="prefList_animations"
        android:summary="@string/prefsList_summary"
        android:title="@string/prefsList_title" >
    </ListPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the list data to a different preference than the one declared in xml. Currently you're setting the data against a newly created `ListPreference`:

```
ListPreference prefListAnim = new ListPreference(this);
```

However, you're displaying the (empty) one declared in xml. You should do either one or the other. For example, the easiest solution is probably to change above to inflate the preference from xml in stead:

```
ListPreference prefListAnim = (ListPreference) findPreference("prefList_animations");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I was doing your method with the find preference to start with , but I moved on because I kept trying diff ways, I fixed my problem as I had another attribute in my xml ' android:dialogMessage="choose"' when I removed this code it all worked out fine, don't know why.